# Simulator showing the ViewController which I have deleted

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

In my application I am using two storyboards, one is for English language and the other is for Arabic language. Now I delete one viewcontroller i.e. "MyOrderHistoryViewController" both from Arabic as well as English storyboards, then I run my application and it's still showing `MyOrderHistoryViewController` which I have deleted on simulator. I am not getting why this is happening, please help me.

Comment: Are you using base localisation? Do you have a storyboard wit "(Base)"?

Comment: Why are you using two storyborad?

Comment: @iDeveloper Why not? There is no problem with storyboard localization, it's a well-used method.

Comment: You can do this thing, By using only one simulator and Localization or Internationalization

Comment: try cleaning your project, including build folder, at Product -> Clean while holding option key

Comment: @Sweeper - yes I am using base localisation

Comment: @iDeveloper - yes we can but not for Arabic language because in Arabic language direction changed from RTL and its difficult to manage many Viewcontrollers constraints RTL with coding that's why I am using two storyboard

Comment: @Fiser33 - I clean the project also the derived data but its not working

Comment: @PalakGarg I am using one simulator for English and Arabic, That's why I suggest this, By the way, it's up to you. All the best